# Send fake sensor value to an Android real device

Tags: adb, sensors

Is possible to simulate an event on a Android real device?

More precisely, I want to test an application which does something if a particular temperature value is detected. Is there an adb command, or somethings else, to send a fake sensor value to the device in order to check the application behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: If the device is rooted you could try the [Android Event Injector](https://github.com/radhoo/android-event-injector) - not sure if this old project is still usable on recent Android versions.

Comment: There is an Xposed module which can do so. https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-disable-proximity-t2798887/post53766106#post53766106#. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3921467/4720957

Comment: Unfortunatelly my device is not rooted hence I can not use Xposed.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically what sensor ? 
If you are simulating a screen press, then yes.

If you are simulating a temperature for your CPU, probably not.

It depends on the level of safety In my opinion, if your just mocking GPS locations, not a big problem... However if your trying to mock temperature readings or something that might cause hardware failure's... it may not be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I would be interested at temperature and pressure sensors.

Comment: I'm fairly sure for user safety reasons, that this is the hardest form of sensor data mocking.

Comment: For example, a CPU set to 0° temperature, could potentially expose your lithium based battery to unnecessary heat, that could potentially end in a life threatening situation or an extremely dangerous one... Lithium mixed with oxygen creates explosive gas, the heat source ( CPU ) is usually directly under the battery compartment and ... If the correct situations are met, goodbye hand, or face, or stomach... i personally was interested in a CPU Cooking software that I was trying to build for tests, however it's extremely hard to mock temperature readings... Pressure readings may also be risky

Comment: I understand the subject, but I don't think that the environmental temperature may be cause this problem, but i don't understand why Google doesn't provide some way to simulate these values as well.